# How to get the oldest entry by <field>

Tags: elasticsearch

For the events below:

```
{
    "time": 10,
    "name": "John",
    "status": true 
},
{
    "time": 20,
    "name": "John",
    "status": false
},
{
    "time": 20,
    "name": "Mary",
    "status": false
},
{
    "time": 10,
    "name": "Mary",
    "status": true
}
```

what is the correct way of searching those which are the oldest ones (field `time`<sup>(1)</sup>) for a given `name`?

For the example above, this means

```
{
    "time": 20,
    "name": "John",
    "status": false
},
{
    "time": 20,
    "name": "Mary",
    "status": false
},
```

I tried to use [order in aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) for that, along the lines of

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {

    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "shortlist": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 1,
        "order" : { "time" : "asc" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I get a

```
"error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "aggregation_execution_exception",
            "reason": "Invalid term-aggregator order path [time]. Unknown aggregation [time]"
         }
```

which to be frank I do not understand.

<sup>(1)</sup> this will actually be a epoch timestamp but I used a short int for simplicity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top1": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{"time":{"order": "desc"}}]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it worked. Would you be so kind and explain in a few words the idea of this search? In particular what is the `10` for? Is this the expected amount of records with a given `name`? Would you know id there is documentation for the concept of "aggregations of aggregations"? (I thought that one could only have one aggregation - which yields a flat list of records with the number of records for each aggregated field)

Comment: `size: 10` (which is actually the default) says to return maximum 10 buckets, meaning 10 groupings by name. You can increase that but the higher the number more costly the query will be. Documentation on sub-aggregations: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#_structuring_aggregations

Comment: Thank you, it makes more sense now - the sub-aggregations actually answer a question I as having earlier ("create buckets of data with a specific criteria, then further work on the data of each bucket separately")